# Pathfinder monster stat block attack section

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

I have noticed something funny with monster stat blocks. There are "Spear +3 (1d6)", "Hoofs -3 (1d4 -2)" or "2x Claws +2 (1d4)". And I started noticing that it strangely copes with Str modifier + BAB. But that kind of notation is more like "MagicalWeaponX +1" up to +5 max according to rules. That bonus is applied to attack roll and damage roll.

So about monster stat block - which case is that in attack section? Is it accumulated bonus monster gets on attacks or is it a "weapon" with modifier to attacks and dmg that is calculated with creature Str/Dex, BAB and other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is the accumulated bonus**

What you see in the stat blocks is the end result of the calculation. The are taking into account BAB, stat modifiers, magic weapons, and other stuff and just give you what you need.

This is obviously different than how you would handle this for a PC, but most monsters don't change much from what their stat block says. They don't gain levels, for example.